# Qt 4.7 - glTexSubImage2D returns GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm using a QGLWidget to draw my own picture via OpenGL in Qt 4.7.2. I use OpenGL because I want to stretch my image fast and with less CPU usage.

For this I have three methods. One to initialize the OpenGL environment, one to update my image data from a different thread and one to draw the image itself.

The problem is that in my updateImage method the call of glTexSubImage2D() return a GL_INVALID_OPERATION error. It tried to debug it with gDEBugger but get only this one error. If I look into the context 1 of my program I only see a Texture with size 0x0, after a call of glTexSubImage2D();

**Init OpenGL**

```
void Class::OpenGLInit(void){
   QGLContext* context = const_cast<QGLContext *>(QGLContext::currentContext());
   if (!context)
   {
    qDebug() << "Can not get current OpenGL context";
    return;
   }
   context->makeCurrent();
   glGenTextures(1,&texture);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
   glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL,0);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL,0);
   glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 1024, 1024, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8, NULL);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);
}
```

**Update image**

```
void Class::updateImage(void){
   dataPointer = (u_int8_t*) malloc(1024*1024*4);
   memcpy(dataPointer,externalBuffer,1024*1024*4);

   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
   glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0, 0,0,1024,1024,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8,dataPointer);
   //This line returns a GL_INVALID_OPERATION 
}
```

**Draw image**

```
void Class::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event){
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.beginNativePainting();
    glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    //Draw black screen
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        //Draw Picture
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2f(0, 0);
        glTexCoord2f(1024, 0);
        glVertex2f(1024, 0);
        glTexCoord2f(1024, 1024);
        glVertex2f(1024,1024);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1024);
        glVertex2f(0, 1024);

glEnd();
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
painter.endNativePainting();
}
```

Comment: updateImage() is a Qt slot. It gets called from another thread by a QT::queuedConnection. So this function should run in the same thread as the other ones

Comment: Have you solved this ?

Answer (score 0):

I just notice that you mentioned "update the image from another thread", right? Your error might be due to missing OGL context in the thread which call the 'updateImage'. Please try to call it in the same thread as the OGL context be init and make current.

Comment: Is this an answer or comment?

Comment: I think this is not the case. The function updateImage() is a Qt slot und gets called over a QT::queuedConnection. The debugger runs  this function in the same thread as paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) and OpenGLInit(void).