# Is it possible to upload only parts of texture that has changed in OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl-es

I display a 2D texture in OpenGL using Qt. Most of the texture is the same from frame to frame but a few horizontal lines may have changed.

My first implementation uploaded the whole texture each frame using
`glTexImage2D`.

In my current implementation I call `glTexStorage2D` in the `initializeGL()` method.
Next I upload only the horizontal lines that have changed using `glTexSubImage2D`. I found this to be way faster.

Unfortunately I have found out that I need to support running my application via Remote Desktop to a Windows 7 PC. In this case I need to use OpenGL ES 2.0 API (ANGLE).

Is it possible to only upload the horizontal lines that have changed in OpenGL ES 2.0?
`glTexSubImage2D` is present in OpenGL ES 2.0 but without `glTexStorage2D` it does not seem to work.

EDIT:
Florian Winters answer worked fine:
I replaced

```
glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGBA8, m_textureWidth, m_textureHeight);
```

with

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, m_textureWidth, m_textureHeight, 0, 
GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);
```

in the initialization, `initGL()`.
For each frame, `paintGL()`, I had to add:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, /*GL_NEAREST*/GL_LINEAR);
```

After `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texName);` to get it working.

Comment: As you are using Qt, you might want to look at this question as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27502105/qt-4-7-gltexsubimage2d-returns-gl-invalid-operation (it could be an issue with threads and GL context, as suggested in one of the answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the texture before you can use `glTexSubImage2D` to update parts of it. This can be done by calling either `glTexStorage2D` or `glTexImage2D`. If `glTexStorage2D` is not available, use `glTexImage2D`, as it has been available since very early versions of OpenGL.

As the [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexSubImage2D.xhtm) of `glTexSubImage2D` says,

> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if the texture array has not been defined by a previous glTexImage2D operation.

Comment: Thank you. glTexImage2D takes a pointer to the data as the last parameter. Can I pass a nullptr since I do not want to upload the whole texture? Also do I call glTexImage2D once or per frame?

Comment: @Andy Yes you can pass a `nullptr`

Comment: It should only be necessary to call `glTexImage2D` once, for example right after you create the texture object, but yes, you can pass a null pointer (read the documentation: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml). The question is, why would you want to pass a null pointer? At some point during initialization, you may want to fill your texture with initial data...